# Spring Social Facebook: Is there a way to get phone number?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

Is there a way to get phone number? I am using SpringSocial and Facebook.fetchObjects doesn't seem to have an option

```
    String accessToken = "trhhh";
    Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);      
    String [] fields = { "id", "about", "age_range", 
            "birthday", "context", "cover", 
            "currency", "devices", "education",
            "email", "favorite_athletes",
            "favorite_teams", "first_name", "gender",
            "hometown", "inspirational_people",
            "installed", "install_type", "is_verified", 
            "languages", "last_name", "link", "locale", 
            "location", "meeting_for", "middle_name", 
            "name", "name_format", "political", 
            "quotes", "payment_pricepoints", "relationship_status",
            "religion", "security_settings", "significant_other",
            "sports", "test_group", "timezone", "third_party_id",
            "updated_time", "verified", "video_upload_limits",
            "viewer_can_send_gift", "website", "work"};
    User userProfile = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The user’s phone number is not available via API.